# Given 4 functions, how do you make a 2x2 histogram in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, python-3.x, histogram

I'm having trouble making a 2x2 histogram in Python where, for each subplot, I have the outputs of a particular function, for 4 functions total.

Here's my current code, that doesn't return anything for the first function:

```
figure1 = pl.figure(1)
pl.subplot(221)
data = []
for tuple_1 in ratio_late(statistics, companies):
    data.append(tuple_1[1])

plt.hist(ratio_late)

pyplot.title("Top 10")

pyplot.xlabel("Companies")

# Would like entries with text rotated 45 degrees

pyplot.ylabel("Minutes")

pyplot.show()
```

I don't know how to make the data be on the y and x axis, along with other struggles.

Never took any plotting lessons and google isn't helping either :/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Always look up [the matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html). Chances are you can find the plot type you need, and the code you can use.

Eg. Here's [a histogram demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_histtypes.html), and [how to stack 4 plots into one](http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_multihist.html)

Comment: Hi jcoppens!

I don't really understand what every single thing does and, as such, I'm struggling to put my data into those fields so that I generate a figure like that for me.

Help?

Comment: @PedroCarvalho, Studythe documentation and play around a bit - I bet you can learn it.

Comment: [http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot), [http://matplotlib.org/users/beginner.html](http://matplotlib.org/users/beginner.html)

Comment: @wwii, I'm getting this error using Canopy!

Unfortunately, your original traceback can not be constructed.

Comment: Pedro, Are you from Brasil? There's a nice [series of video on use of pylab and python in Portugues](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZfnPkkLCA0). And [here's a tutorial](http://pyvideo.org/video/617/plotting-with-matplotlib) in English.

Comment: @jcoppens I am but those brasilian tutorials aren't helping me.

By the way, what can I install to have Python's IDLE 2.7 work with pyplot, pylab and whatever else? Canopy isn't working for me!

Comment: I use the Geany editor for my Python programs (not IDLE) but I'm on Linux - I suspect you are using Windows. To install pylab and friends you will need the library 'matplotlib'. And you will probably need 'numpy' too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `pyplot`,

> matplotlib.pyplot is stateful, in that it keeps track of the current
>   figure and plotting area, and the plotting functions are directed to
>   the current axes

(from the [beginners tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/beginner.html)). That means that each time you create a subplot, it will become the current `axis`. So:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [[1,2,3,4,5], [5,4,3,2,1], [1,1,3,3,1], [5,1,5,1,5]]
# 2x2, first axis
plt.subplot(221)
plt.plot(data[0])
# 2x2, second axis
plt.subplot(222)
plt.plot(data[1])
# 2x2, third axis
plt.subplot(223)
plt.plot(data[2])
# 2x2, fourth axis
plt.subplot(224)
plt.plot(data[3])

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image]

Comment: What if I want a vertical bar chart with ylabel, particular values on the y axis, names of a company on the x axis?

Comment: By the way, I have to use pylab

Comment: @PedroCarvalho, from the docs ```pylab is a convenience module that bulk imports matplotlib.pyplot (for plotting) and numpy (for mathematics and working with arrays) in a single name space``` -  with ```pylab``` you can use ```pyplot```.  Look through the gallery ac jcoppens suggests and see if something suits your needs.

Comment: I got this structure set. Now I need to separate the outputs of each of 4 functions into this structure. How do I do that?